# Why does django insert padding and characters into my html file?

Tags: html, css, django

Over the last few days I've been experimenting with Django. I've had some issues with random characters (notably '<') and what I would describe as padding appearing in my html files.

I decided to ignore using Django and rewrote a test template with just html/css. It worked perfectly, and I thought that perhaps it had been an error in my HTML/CSS, until I put the Django template code back in. Now, even though I've removed the Django code and moved the files outside of the root directory for the project, the problem persists. I can't see why this has happened, and the error appears in Firefox, Chrome and even IE. The source looks right in these browsers, [but right click -> inspect in Google Chrome shows there's something not right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0oUr.png)

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <<div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#container {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    margin:0% 25% 0% 25%;
}
#header {
    height:150px;
        background:#7e9bc9;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom:100px;
}
#footer {
    background:#b4c8e8;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}

.nav {
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    bottom:-130px;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    height:30px;
    width:20%;
}

.nav li a {
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color:#093275;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:15px;
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Needless to say, I couldn't find similar questions searching Google or stackexchange. Maybe I'm not asking the 'right' question, so please feel free to direct me to an answer if one exists.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have that line

```
<<div id="content"></div>
```

Double `<` character, which is wrong.

Comment: That simple! I think I was going a little crazy after a few errors with Django, thank you.

Comment: Cheers! You can use some sort of linter or IDEs, that already include them and they would be highlighted.